# How to handle CNAME requirement for zone apex DNS record in AWS Route53 and Cloudflare

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53, cloudflare

It is not possible to create a CNAME for the apex zone in Route53 - it violates RFC. Route53 provides for an ALIAS record, but this record has to point to another AWS service and is not capable of pointing to an external service like Cloudflare.

There's a lot of posts about this issue. Most of them end up suggesting some complex setup leveraging additional AWS services to redirect the apex zone to a sub-domain. i.e. mydomain.com redirects to [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) or utilizing AWS load balancers to tunnel the traffic. Neither of these are optimal and I am concerned about the extra complexity and possible service interruptions or side-effects. The simplest of these is using an S3 website endpoint - but it doesn't support HTTPS.

What I cannot find are any definitive resources for handling this scenario in a more elegant way (directly at the DNS level), especially as it applies to Cloudflare. It appears the primary solution would be to change the zone nameservers to Cloudflare. But, there is no desire to have Cloudflare take over DNS resolution for the entire domain.

Am I missing something? Is there any way I can point `mydomain.com` directly to a Cloudflare DNS record for web services, without disrupting or moving the entire `mydomain.com` zone in Route53, or setting up redirection or tunneling?